# In a transaction of Mysql Innodb, is the sql execution orderly?

Tags: mysql, innodb

If multiple DML statements are executed in one transaction, will Innodb execute them sequentially? Or will it be reordered?

```sql
update t_x ... where id = 1;
update t_x ... where id = 2;
update t_x ... where id = 3;
...
update t_x where id = n;
```

Comment: Reordered - no.  "Simultaneously" - yes.

Comment: Does“Simultaneously” mean there could be disorder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL statements are executed sequentially. They are not reordered.

See this example:

```
mysql> create table mytable (i int);

mysql> begin;

mysql> insert into mytable values (10);

mysql> update mytable set i = i + 10;

mysql> update mytable set i = i * 10;

mysql> commit;

mysql> select * from mytable;
+------+
| i    |
+------+
|  200 |
+------+
```

In this example, the order of statements is important to get a deterministic result. If the statements were reordered, the result might come back as 110 instead of 200.